# A Problem on Euler's totient function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function

**Find all m,n such that φ(mn)=φ(n)**

here φ is the euler's totient function.

My attempt:
So i split this up into two cases, *note: { (m,n) = gcd(m,n) }*

Case 1: (m,n)=1 , Then we'd get φ(m)φ(n)=φ(n) which would imply m=1 and n is any integer or m=2 and n is an odd integer. Simple enough,

Case 2: (m,n) is not 1. Well here, things get tricky. I could not figure out much so i checked a lot of examples and came up with φ(m)φ(n) = $φ(mn) / (m,n)$ if (m,n) is a prime. I am not even sure if this result is correct or not. And if (m,n) was composite, well then i could't understand what to even do.

Any help/hint would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $\varphi(m)=1$ does not imply $m=1$. There is another value that works.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes i know it implies m=1 or 2

Comment: Oh, I see; you aren't phrasing it very clearly, I'm afraid... But sorry for implying you did not state it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you know how to solve this problem or whether case 2 is even necessary, ie. does there exist a solution for case 2

Comment: Well, it's necessary in that you have to deal with the case; you can't just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution in case 2.

If there is a prime number $p$ that divides both $m$ and $n$, then we would have $\varphi(pn)\mid \varphi(mn)$, and also $\varphi(pn) = p\varphi(n)$.

This means that $\varphi(mn)$ cannot be equal to $\varphi(n)$ in that case.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful solution. I just have one question, are the two results you used pretty standard? coz i had never seen them before even tho they are easy to prove, i don't know how i would have thought of that/

Comment: These are not "standard" in the sense that they are probably not stated in a normal textbook, but as you see, they are easy to prove.

Comment: so may i just ask one last thing, how did you get the the motivation to think of these two identities?

Comment: I'd say it's based on experience...